# android java endswith keeps crashing

Tags: java, android

I'm having a error with my code when i run it...All i want to do to make a webview in order to show a webpage in my app and to check the url if it ends with .m3u8 and then if it ends with .mp4 to open with the mxplayer(it's a media player app from the play store). I got the API of mxplayer from their site and added into my code but the problem is that when the link ends with .mp4 it crashes. Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("url");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // Api < 24
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView myWebView, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
                intent.setDataAndType( videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL" );
                intent.setPackage( "com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro" );
                startActivity( intent );
                return true;

            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: please post your Logcat too..

Comment: Sorry i cant because my CPU doesn't supports the ADB to run the apps so i transfer them manually to my phone